# Save a date field to Parse : invalid type for key, expected date, but got string

Tags: javascript, datetime, parse-platform

I have a very strange problem because some weeks ago, all worked well.
But now, I cannot save a object containing a Date.

I use the Parse.com backend.
I have a very simple class with just one field Date.

I do a very simple query :

```
var Day = Parse.Object.extend('Day');
var d = new Day();
var now = new Date();
d.set('dateField', now);
d.save();
```

I get an error :

> invalid type for key dateField, expected date, but got string

if I try to do that :

```
d.set('dateField', {__type:"Date", iso:now.toISOString()}
```

I've got the same problem...

I hope somebody can help me, because, I have not any idea...

Thanks !

Comment: Using `d.set('dateField', now)` is the correct way to do it in JavaScript, if that first block of code failed then you should file a bug report as that has worked fine for me. I would try that simple query again as shown in a file with nothing but the bare minimum scripts attached.

Comment: My previous example is exactly what I tried and it doesn't work. I don't have Cloud Code, I tried through a script and through browser's console. It is very strange because others fields are okay.

Comment: I suggest filing a bug report at https://parse.com/help

Comment: I'm going to report that

Comment: if you've ended up here looking for the correct way to use a `momentjs` date in a `Parse.Query` for comparison purposes, pass the date as `myDate.toDate()` (e.g. `var today = moment().startOf('day'); query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('updatedAt', today.toDate());`)

Answer (score 3):

Don't know what are you doing wrong there but this snippet works correctly for me. It is tested & working correctly.

Quick double check which you can make - COLUMN NAME of CLASS, NAME of CLASS, DATATYPE of the COlUMN, JS SDK version in SCRIPT TAG

```js
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("APPID", "JS KEY");
    
    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("CLASSNAME");
 var currentDate = new Date();
    var testObject = new TestObject();
 testObject.set('datefield', currentDate);
      testObject.save(null, {
      success: function(object) {
        $(".success").show();
      },
      error: function(model, error) {
     console.log('error - ', error);
        $(".error").show();
      }
    });
  </script>
```